What should the Startup.cs and Program.cs files contain in .NET 4.6.1
I have manually changed the target framework of my Web API from .NET 8 to .NET 4.6.1 for compatibility reasons. My question now is how I should change my Program.cs file and other config files for the program to run.
Currently I have altered the Program.cs file and added a Startup.cs file, such that both of these look like this:
Program.cs:
using System;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;

namespace MobileAppApi
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/";
 
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Web API running at " + baseAddress);
                Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to quit.");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}

Startup.cs:
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Unity;
using Unity.Lifetime;
using MobileAppApi.Api.Controllers;
using MobileAppApi.Api.Services;
using MobileAppApi.Api.Interfaces;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MobileAppApi.Startup))]

namespace MobileAppApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            ConfigureWebApi(config);
            ConfigureDependencyInjection(config);
    
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    
        private void ConfigureWebApi(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
    
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        }
    
        private void ConfigureDependencyInjection(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
    
            container.RegisterType<IArticleService, ArticleService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<ArticlesController>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    
            config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
        }
    }
}

While the program does "run" and I can see the console.logs in the terminal, I cannot debug the APIs, so clearly my API is not running. All other errors have been fixed so far.

I think you should be targeting either .NET8, or .NET Standard 2.1.

@browsermator where should I change that? In the csproj file? And I have to run on 4.6.1

You are NOT running on 4.6.1.  That's a different framework/run-time.  .NET8 is core.  You might select .NET Standard 2.0 and still be safe... I think the target can be set in publish options.  See here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-standard-2-1/#net-platform-support

You might specify what "compatibility reasons" are here.  You can probably just publish self-contained (includes run-time) to get around those.

My program must be able to access System.Web.HttpContext without injection.

You might check here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0
